# Best way to order CSS/JavaScript external files includes

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1

What is the best way to include CSS external files? from general to specific or the opposite?

More precisely in Rails 3.1, the default application.css (no Sass) generated contains:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

It goes from specific to general so I guess if I want to add jQuery UI theme for example, the best would be:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 *= require jquery-ui/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css
 */
```

instead of:

```
/*
 *= require jquery-ui/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

I ask this question because I know that for example in C++ it is recommended to go from the most specific to the most general.

The same question stands for .js includes, by default Rails generates (no CoffeeScript):

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Here it seems to go the opposite: from general to specific.

Did the Rails devs choose a default sorting on purpose, or is it just random? If there is no preferable way from a technical point of vue, what are the conventions usually used?

Comment: Quick answer is that in th website environament its -normally- from general to specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS has to be included with general rules first and then more specific rules.  This allows the more specific rules to always override the general rules (in the cases where you want that to happen) without explicitly having to manage [CSS specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

So, if you had these two CSS rules:

```
// general rule
.subitem {color: blue;}

// more specific rule
.currentitem {color: red;}
```

And, you had HTML like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="subitem">Item</li>
    <li class="subitem currentitem">Item</li>
    <li class="subitem">Item</li>
    <li class="subitem">Item</li>
</ul>
```

You would want to make sure that the more specific rule for `.currentItem` came after the more general rule for `.subitem` so that the `.currentitem` rule would be in effect when you wanted it to be.

Javascript files must be included in an appropriate dependency order.  For example, if you have javascript file B that uses functions in file A in it's initialization code, then file A must be included before file B.  If two javascript files have no initialization dependencies (e.g. they don't call functions in each other at initialization), then they can be in any order.

FYI, in javascript files, you should make sure that no functions in the global namespace or in a specific namespace exist with the same name in multiple files.  If so, the last one to be included will be the one that is in effect.  In general, you should not rely on this behavior, but should remove conflicting functions with the same name.

Comment: Can you define *more specificity* in the context in which you describe?

Comment: So if `.subitem` was added to the page after `.currentitem`, it would override `.currentitem`?

Comment: One thing I'd add on the CSS side is that you should probably enforce the specificity by doing `.subitem.currentitem`, instead of relying on the order.  That kind of 'cascading' is what CSS is for :)

Comment: Reference add for CSS Specificity.  A simple Google search for "CSS specificity" will yield more helpful pages than you have time to read.   The first result in that search is this helpful one: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/.

Comment: @mtyson - yes, you could do it that way to make it intolerant of CSS order, but there are definitely places where order matters and I'm just trying to create an example to show how order works.  It's a good idea to put general CSS stuff first and more specific CSS later.

Comment: My understanding is the OP is asking about the order of linked stylesheets. Specificity, as far as I understand it, would be guided by the selector and it's "closeness" to the element effected by the cascading rules, with `style` attributes being closest. The order of a class name is secondary to the argument, but the order of entry, at least as far as I can tell, is the context in question.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - yes, in my example, if the CSS for `.subitem` was after the CSS for `.currentitem`, then in this example, the CSS for `.currentitem` would never be in effect.

Comment: @jfriend00 - If true, that's an interesting twist. Hmm. Would this be true for `style` element selectors?

Comment: @jfriend00 - http://jsfiddle.net/RQJX6/1/ This is one of those blind spots that I haven't ever questioned in detail.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - was there a question in your last two comments?  If two CSS rules targeting the same object have the exact same CSS specificity, then the CSS stylesheet rule that came last will have precedence.

Comment: @jfriend00 - *Would this be true for `style` element selectors?* See the jsfiddle and the order of `selectitem` and `customitem`, which seems to support what you're saying.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - Yes.  CSS rules defined in `<style>` sections are treated no differently than externally imported stylesheets.  They are processed in the order they appear in the page.

Comment: @jfriend00 - http://jsfiddle.net/RQJX6/2/ I always thought `#` selectors would override class selectors, no matter the order. At least I (apparently) had that right.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - if you want to know the rules for CSS precedence, then you should read them and understand them.  You seem to be picking up pieces of it, but it is a bit more involved than you have described in your comments.  Most of the articles you find in a google search for "CSS Specificity" are quite good so there is no need for me to reproduce that info here.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I did several years ago read through a lot of articles (including A List Apart), but my understanding at this point is more instinct than specific; I would probably benefit from a rereading, since I have a decent grasp of it now, as opposed to then. I actually thought you were saying something different at first, but now I see you're saying what I was thinking initially. I probably need to bone up on the details again, at least as reinforcement.

Answer (score 0):

include css from css file:

```
@import "myCSSfile.css";
```

include css from html:

```
<link href="myCSSfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

include css from javascript:

```
document.getElementByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML +=
  '<link href="myCSSfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">';
```

Answer (score -1):

One thing I'd add on the CSS side is that you should probably enforce the specificity by doing .subitem.currentitem, instead of relying on the order. That kind of 'cascading' is what CSS is for :)

In large apps, depending on the order will get tricky.

Also, in the case of JS, the order will affect what is assigned to an identifier, if it is defined more than once.